# how to get the index value from the table?

Tags: indexing

I'm trying to get the index value for the column that I create index. How to do this? What I mean is something like below:-

```
 index value     indexed field data
    ______________ ____________________ 
    0                apple
    1                orange
    2                manggo
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Index in database? Some other "index"? If database, what database?

Comment: Hi Joachim, yes index in database( mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Use $index.

More info: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEpbjve5iHk

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="fruit in fruitBasket">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>                      <!-- --------See this line! -->
        <td>{{fruit}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```